# Failed binder transaction when putting an bitmap dynamically in a widget

Tags: android, bitmap, widget

Can anybody tell me the reason for **failed binder transaction** error? I can see this error message in logcat.
I am getting this error while trying to put an bitmap dynamically in a widget...

Answer (score 92):

This is caused because all the changes to the RemoteViews are serialised (e.g. setInt and setImageViewBitmap ). The bitmaps are also serialised into an internal bundle. Unfortunately this bundle has a very small size limit.

You can solve it by scaling down the image size this way:

```
 public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

 final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

 int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
 int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

 photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

 return photo;
 }
```

Choose newHeight to be small enough (~100 for every square it should take on the screen) and use it for your widget, and your problem will be solved :)

Comment: What I don't quite understand is what happens here exactly. I'm using a ViewPager with a fairly large dataset, yet it does remember everything between pages despite the binder error spam. Does the bundle get written to local storage and then prefetched or what? Can I possibly lose data if I add more pages?

Comment: But this will reduce the image quality

Answer (score 65):

You can compress the bitmap as an byte's array and then uncompress it in another activity, like this.

Compress!!

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 
        setresult.putExtra("BMP",bytes);
```

Uncompress!!

```
        byte[] bytes = data.getByteArrayExtra("BMP");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: Perfect, this significantly reduces the bitmap size.

Comment: why not use JPEG instead of PNG? isnt it better compressed?

Comment: @mehmet6parmak PNG is used because it is lossless, unlike JPEG. Yes, JPEG compresses better, but the quality (somewhat) suffers as a result.

Comment: doesn't work for me :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540819/still-get-error-failed-binder-transaction-although-have-compressed-it

Comment: Kudos! Great workaround for a temporary implementation I was working on. Although passing heavy data should be avoided while using Bundles/Intents.

Comment: What is the `bmp` variable?

Answer (score 38):

The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions are of moderate size.

refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

Answer (score 13):

See my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285546/failed-binder-transaction-while-passing-bitmap-from-one-activity-to-another/27333282)
thread.

`intent.putExtra("Some string",very_large_obj_for_binder_buffer);`

You are exceeding the binder transaction buffer by transferring large element(s) from one activity to another activity.

Comment: I had same issue I just remove putExtra problem sorted!

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this issue by storing images on internal storage and then using .setImageURI() rather than .setBitmap().

Comment: and don't pass the images through Parcelable from screen to screen or so, I guess that's worst in this case

Answer (score 3):

The right approach is to use `setImageViewUri()` (slower) or the `setImageViewBitmap()` and recreating `RemoteView`s every time you update the notification.