# Failed binder transaction android bitmap

Tags: android, android-camera, bitmapimage

Please find below a code snippet of what i am trying.

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {            
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
String encoded = encodeTobase64(bMap);
Intent i = new Intent(Photocapture.this, ConfirmCapture.class);
i.putExtra("img", encoded);
startActivity(i);           
}
};
protected String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
Bitmap immagex = image;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);      
return imageEncoded;
}
```

When i execute this, i get failed binder transaction. I am developing a custom camera application. Any inputs will be of great help to proceed with!

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8688576/521728

Comment: Thanks, resolved the same way!