# startActivity(intent) is not working

Tags: android

I am working on an application. In which I stuck in a problem. My problem is that when I am calling `startActivity(intent)` then it's not working and my `logcat` shows

!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION!!!

Please help me out this problem. 
Thanks

My code is

```
listview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
long arg3) 
{    



LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearlist);
selected_section_id=webservice_sectionid.get(arg2);
                      selected_section_heading=webservice_sectionheading.get(arg2);
selected_section_no=webservice_sectionno.get(arg2);

String[] array_sectionid = new String[webservice_sectionid.size()];
                String[] array_sectionheading = new  String[webservice_sectionheading.size()];
String[] array_sectionno = new String[webservice_sectionno.size()];
String noofpage=String.valueOf(webservice_sectionno.size());
Intent intent = null;

intent=new Intent(Ruleservice1.this,SectionWebPage1.class);
intent.putExtra("SectionId", selected_section_id);
intent.putExtra("SectionHeading", selected_section_heading);
intent.putExtra("ActId", selectedvalue_id);
intent.putExtra("SelectListPosition", String.valueOf(arg2)); 
intent.putExtra("ActId_g", (ArrayList<String>) webservice_global_actid); 
intent.putExtra("ActHeading_g", (ArrayList<String>) webservice_global_actheading);   
intent.putExtra("SectionId1", selected_section_id1);
intent.putExtra("SectionNo", selected_section_no);
intent.putExtra("SectionNo1", selected_section_no1);
intent.putExtra("ActHeading", selectedvalue_heading);
intent.putExtra("array_sectionid", (ArrayList<String>) webservice_sectionid);
intent.putExtra("array_sectionheading", (ArrayList<String>) webservice_sectionheading);
intent.putExtra("array_sectionno", (ArrayList<String>) webservice_sectionno);
intent.putExtra("arrayActId", (ArrayList<String>)webservice_actid);
intent.putExtra("arrayActHeading", (ArrayList<String>)webservice_actheading);
intent.putExtra("flag", "0");
intent.putExtra("offlineStatus", offlineflag+"");
intent.putExtra("count", "Page "+String.valueOf(arg2+1)+" of "+  webservice_sectionno.size());
intent.putExtra("fromwhichpage", "rule");
intent.putExtra("noofpage", noofpage);
intent.putExtra("searchtext", SearchText);
intent.putExtra("hideshowtext", "Show");
intent.putExtra("arrayActCatid", selectedcatid);
startActivity(intent);
}

});
```

My Logcat

```
10-10 13:02:23.453: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3009K, 31% free 11791K/17031K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-10 13:02:23.563: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 31% free 11790K/17031K, paused 26ms
10-10 13:02:23.573: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.275MB for 3738592-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:23.643: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 26% free 15441K/20743K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-10 13:02:23.663: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4544K, 48% free 10898K/20743K, paused 27ms
10-10 13:02:23.673: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.403MB for 3738642-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:23.733: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 30% free 14548K/20743K, paused 26ms
10-10 13:02:23.743: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.751MB for 5607958-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:23.803: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3651K, 38% free 16374K/26247K, paused 1ms+4ms
10-10 13:02:23.833: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 38% free 16374K/26247K, paused 29ms
10-10 13:02:23.843: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.751MB for 3738646-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:23.903: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 24% free 20025K/26247K, paused 28ms
10-10 13:02:23.913: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.317MB for 3738700-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:23.973: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5476K, 40% free 18199K/29959K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-10 13:02:24.013: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3651K, 52% free 14548K/29959K, paused 31ms
10-10 13:02:24.023: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.751MB for 5608046-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:24.093: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3651K, 54% free 16374K/35463K, paused 30ms
10-10 13:02:24.123: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 54% free 16374K/35463K, paused 32ms
10-10 13:02:24.133: I/dalvikvm-heap(2527): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.751MB for 3738702-byte allocation
10-10 13:02:24.203: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 44% free 19896K/35463K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-10 13:02:24.503: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5969K, 56% free 15957K/35463K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-10 13:02:24.803: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 507K, 51% free 17497K/35463K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-10 13:02:25.143: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 476K, 47% free 19115K/35463K, paused 3ms+6ms
10-10 13:02:25.473: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 508K, 42% free 20684K/35463K, paused 2ms+6ms
10-10 13:02:25.813: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 476K, 38% free 22256K/35463K, paused 2ms+6ms
10-10 13:02:26.163: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 501K, 33% free 23796K/35463K, paused 2ms+6ms
10-10 13:02:26.553: D/dalvikvm(2527): GC_CONCURRENT freed 915K, 30% free 24981K/35463K, paused 2ms+7ms
10-10 13:02:28.643: E/JavaBinder(2527): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: try to pass `JSON String` and convert it in called activity.

Comment: looks like your data is too big to go in an intent.

Comment: You are overfilling that Intent... you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Jox@: you are right what i do to solve my problem because i have to send data over other activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: `intent.putExtra("searchtext", SearchText);` looks wrong, probably a copy paste error?

Also, make sure that you don't put a lot of data into the Intent. String values and Integers are fine but you seem to be passing application data with ArrayLists, that's not how you transport information from one Activity to the other. You should either put them in a database and only transfer the relevant ids or store them in some cache that you an reference from every activity (like the application object).

Also check the link that Tim posted.

Answer (score 1):

i just found this -> [Failed binder transaction when putting an bitmap dynamically in a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction)

In this Post they say this error is because of to big data.
I do not know if this will be the same reason, but try if the error also occurs if u pass less data with the intent.
In my link above, they write about a limit of 1 MB.

And btw sorry for my bad english. =)