# Start activity to another intent is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I made a new project using navigation drawer that android gives me as builtin and then i added my menus in the navigation Drawer and then made another activity that is empty activity and made a button over there of getStarted and on the click listening i made an intent of the mainActivity that has the navigation drawer and then assigned this to the getstarted button to startActivity(mainIntent) but its not working, I have done many R&D but didn't work at all and i am getting following errors.

I have tried all the discussion [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289586/startactivityintent-is-not-working)

but nothing is working in my case

```
class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
        getStartedBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val main = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(main)
        }
    }
```

I want to be routed to the main activity.In main activity I have used builtin toolbar or navigation drawer.

Comment: What does "not working" mean to you here? What are the "following errors"?

Comment: what is the context of "this" in onClickListener, try changing it to activity context.

Answer (score 1):

> To access **this** from an outer scope (a class, or extension function, or labeled function literal with receiver) we write this@label where @label is a label on the scope this is meant to be from:

You should specify your scope. For more information you can check this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html).

```
val main = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(main)
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Hi Ensar, i would not say that your answer is wrong, but next time consider explaining why specific changes to the code have to be made. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I edited my answer with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `val main = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)` to val main = `Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,MainActivity::class.java)`

Also make sure that `getStartedBtn` is correctly imported from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you imported getStartedBtn correctly and try to change the `val main = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)` to `val main = Intent(applicatonContext,MainActivity::class.java)` it thought this will help if you still facing any problem please post the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't manually create the class or the xml for the MainActivity. Create it by right clicking on com.example.filename > New > Activity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33913807)