# Android java binder FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION?

Tags: android, android-binder

I am trying to download an image from service and display it in activity but I keep getting

```
 java binder FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION
```

This is my service Code

```
public class DownloadImageService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new LoadImageAsync().execute(intent.getStringExtra("type"));
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private class LoadImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    byte[] compressedImage;
    Bitmap bmp;
    String img;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            compressedImage = CompressBitmap.compresssImage(bmp);
            img = Base64.encodeToString(compressedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            compressedImage = null;
            bmp = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (compressedImage != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherCampaignActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("image_byte", img);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadImageService.class));
    }
}
```

}

Compress function

```
public static byte[] compresssImage(Bitmap b) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] compressedByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return compressedByteArray;
}
```

My ACTIVITY

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCam);
    byte[] byteArray =      Base64.decode(getIntent().getStringExtra("image_byte"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    //        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("image_byte");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
}
```

What is the issue in the code. The activity is not starting.

the app is not crashing. I only get this in logcat:

```
06-30 12:38:36.800 29992-29992/com.vt.enit E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

It is probably due to large bitmap I guess.

Comment: whats the whole stack trace?

Comment: the app is not crashing. I only get this: 06-30 12:38:36.800  29992-29992/com.vt.enit E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: so before you call `startActivity(i)` (after `i.putExtra("image_byte", img);`) try to Log.d `img` size

Comment: I am getting the image size before and after calling start activity.

Comment: and what do you see in the logcat?

Comment: 3051kb is the bitmap  size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81937/discussion-between-wishy-and-pskink).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction

Comment: You shouldn't put a bitmap through binder, that is a very BAD idea. Binder is limited in terms of how much space is available, figure out some other way to share it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creating the cache of the image solves my problem

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
// OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
// int in its constructor.
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

// Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
        // number of items.
        return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
    }
};
...
}

public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
    mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
}
 }

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

Reference : [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: what is String key in this?

Comment: Lrucache works as a key value pair. You can give any key eg "profile" and access the bitmap with this key only

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Any problems making LruCache reference static?

Comment: @JustinCase I don't think there will be any problems making it static. LruCache will remain active till the lifecycle of the application.

Answer (score 8):

It fails because you are trying to send an image as an intent extra and it is too large for it. You can't send image using IPC communication technics like intents or service/binder, there is a limit of 1mb/10mb depending on version of android.