# Still get error FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION although have compressed it

Tags: android, image, android-camera, image-gallery

I wanted to return the image from **AddMoreClaims** to **AddClaims** `listView`. When I click the submit `button` in **AddMoreClaims** , I get message `E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` .

I use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18476263/5156075) but still getting this annoying message !

**AddMoreClaims**

```
Bitmap bmp,photo;
byte[] bytes;

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK & data != null && data.getData () !=null) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    try
                    {
                        photo= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        bytes= stream.toByteArray();
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp); // image get displayed
                    }catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
```

The selected image will be displayed on `imageView` **AddMoreClaims**.

When submit `button` is clicked, I want it return to **AddClaims**.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("BMP", bmp);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

What's wrong here ? Have I missed out anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not compressing the bmp where you should do it.

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        returnIntent.putExtra("BMP", bytes);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

Then you should to uncompress where you need to show the image

```
byte[] bytes = data.getByteArrayExtra("BMP");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use compress large data into intent, this will consume more cpu and time,
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131640/android-java-binder-failed-binder-transaction) thread.
If compressed data also exceed the limit of binder, also get this error: `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`