# Compress and decompress bitmap - 'FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION'

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to pass the image data to another activity after taking photo or get from the gallery. But I got this error 'FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION', so I did some research and i think it's because the file size to big, I need to compress it and decompress in another activity. But the decompress code seem not working, the image is pixelated and blur.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Why? How to fix it?

**First Activity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    inputStreamImg = null;

    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA) {
            try {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);
                byte[] byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
                goProgressDetailPage(byteArray);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            if (selectedImage==null){
                return;
            }

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);
                byte[] byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
                goProgressDetailPage(byteArray);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void goProgressDetailPage(byte[] byteArray){
    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), EditProgressActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("viewString",byteArray);
    getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
byte[] bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("viewString");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
//decompress fail, the image is blur
base64img = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("image uploaded", ""+base64img);
//upload base64 to server...
```

Related Question:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction-when-putting-an-bitmap-dynamically-in-a-widget#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction-when-putting-an-bitmap-dynamically-in-a-widget#_=_)

[Still get error FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION although have compressed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540819/still-get-error-failed-binder-transaction-although-have-compressed-it)

Answer (score 0):

As you said,

You need to pass the image after capturing it.So, the concept is that you just take the photo and **save it to your device and get the path** of the image location.Now **just pass the path** throughout your activities.

As per your need you do not have to compress or decompress the image.

Comment: `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` pass this?

Comment: do you have any tutorial or reference about save the image and decode the path to bitmap?

Comment: You can try this.I think this will solve your issue though I have used compress method now.                                                                       Uri mUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), mImage);
     public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap mImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), mImage, "ImageTitle", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}   Use this code to decode the path from image bitmap.