# How to Schedule Notification in Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to set notification for a time in the future.
I have the code for creating a notification but I can't find an option to schedule it.

How can I schedule notifications?

Comment: This is still useful because the other question was 3 years before this one and some underlying behaviour has changed, so thanks!

Comment: If anyone is still facing the same issue, this might help: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use `PendingIntent` and `BroadCastReceiver` for this -

```
public void scheduleNotification(Context context, long delay, int notificationId) {//delay is after how much time(in millis) from current time you want to schedule the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.content))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon)).getBitmap())
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(activity);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyNotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Also, you need to show notification in your receiver class -

```
public class MyNotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification_id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
}
```

Finally, call `scheduleNotification()` with appropriate arguments and you are good to go!

Comment: so everyday at 12PM for example... are those code going in main activity?

Comment: This code scheduled alarm will be cancel when app is swipe in "recent apps list". How do avoid this issue?

Comment: Seems like the accepted answer should be the one below by apelsoczi.. Seems relatively useless to schedule a notification without a guarantee of delivery on the scheduled date if the phone is restarted.

Comment: This answer is INCORRECT, because you are putting images to the intent. This is anti-pattern and might cause errors. Please have a lookt at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407821/how-to-solve-error-failed-binder-transaction-in-android-4-4

Comment: is YourActivity.class the caller activity? the solution did not work

Comment: `YourActivity` is the activity you want to launch when user taps on the notification.

Comment: Won't work unless you add the following in AndroidManifest.xml
`<receiver android:name=".MyNotificationPublisher" />` under `<application>` tag. Note, MyNotificationPublisher.java is in the same folder.

Answer (score 46):

**NOT FOR USE IN OREO+ (edit)**

The answers above are good - **but don't consider the user's potential to restart the device** (which clears PendingIntent's scheduled by AlarmManager).

You need to create a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, which will contain an AlarmManager to schedule deliver a PendingIntent. When the WakefulBroadcastReceiver handles the intent - post your notification and signal the WakefulBroadcastReceiver to complete.

**WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

```
    /**
     * When the alarm fires, this WakefulBroadcastReceiver receives the broadcast Intent
     * and then posts the notification.
     */
    public class WakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        // provides access to the system alarm services.
        private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //// TODO: post notification
            WakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

        /**
         * Sets the next alarm to run. When the alarm fires,
         * the app broadcasts an Intent to this WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
         * @param context the context of the app's Activity.
         */
        public void setAlarm(Context context) {
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WakefulReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //// TODO: use calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,MINUTE,HOUR, int);
            //calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            //ALWAYS recompute the calendar after using add, set, roll
            Date date = calendar.getTime();

            mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), alarmIntent);

            // Enable {@code BootReceiver} to automatically restart when the
            // device is rebooted.
            //// TODO: you may need to reference the context by ApplicationActivity.class
            ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }

        /**
         * Cancels the next alarm from running. Removes any intents set by this
         * WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
         * @param context the context of the app's Activity
         */
        public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
            Log.d("WakefulAlarmReceiver", "{cancelAlarm}");

            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WakefulReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            mAlarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);

            // Disable {@code BootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart when the device is rebooted.
            //// TODO: you may need to reference the context by ApplicationActivity.class
            ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
```

**BootReceiver**

```
    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            context = ApplicationActivity.class;
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WakefulReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //// TODO: use calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,MINUTE,HOUR, int);
            //calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            //ALWAYS recompute the calendar after using add, set, roll
            Date date = calendar.getTime();

            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), alarmIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".WakefulReceiver"/>

<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This is gold! Glad to find it.

Comment: Hey on the `BootReceiver.class` you shouldn't use manually type "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" rather use `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: Remember to add permission into Manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: Hey, this works even if the app is not running at the moment of the notification? Thanks

Comment: @MartinGian yes it does, following the parameter annotation reference for WakefulBroadcastReceiver#setAlarm `@param context the context of the app's Activity.`

Comment: WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated in Android 8.0. Hence this solution may not work for Android 8.0

Comment: thanks, i think you can simply use a broadcast receiver - will revisit this answer and remove disclaimer at top of post

Comment: The solution for Android 8 Oreo seems to be to extend `BroadcastReceiver` instead of `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825690/5824489

Comment: @SARose Hi, can you explain why you recommended using ".ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" rather than ".BOOT_COMPLETED"?

Comment: Can anyone edit with an explanation of why It should not be used in SDK 26+?

Comment: What is ApplicationActivity.class?

Comment: deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver