# Send local push notifications for Android PWA without Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, local

I'm working on a progressive web app (PWA) that is targeting Android users.
Is it possible to schedule and send local push notifications without using a Cordova WebView and [Plugin like this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, yes! you can.

How? By using the native Push API with Notification API. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) have great documentation for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you schedule them for offline use - is this possible at all?

Comment: @Tom As far as I know, you need either: Process, aka. Service Worker to maintain it manually i.e implement your own scheduler, or a [Browser API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432441/is-there-a-way-to-schedule-offline-notifications-in-a-pwa) let you do that, see [this also](https://web.dev/notification-triggers/).