# PWA Notifications without push

Tags: javascript, notifications, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-worker

Is there a way to reliably get a PWA to send push notifications using the FE's state alone?

Right now I have quite a simple usecase, where I want some PWAs I have to send push notifications on timers set by the user.

This doesn't require any server-side logic, the service worker can always know the time.

However, I've seen no way to do this. The intuitive way is to use a `setInterval` that executes every minute and checks the time, but browsers seem to throttle the worker after a while.

The alternative is to use the push API but this seems to actually be more expensive in terms of resources and much less elegant to setup.

Is there a way to get push notifications to fire in a FE-only way when the PWA is foregrounded?

Comment: There was a proposal for this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/notification-triggers, but it was abandoned. You can still use it behind the experimental web platform features flag

Comment: I don't know what FE you are talking about, but scheduling something to run in the future (without having the webpage running) is currently not possible using only a PWA. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435090/2104665