# I compressed bitmap of image but it wouldn't go to the next activity

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am developing an android app. In this after taking a picture from gallery it will go to next page. but when I use small size of image,it works. But larger size is not working. I compressed bitmap. But still now problem exists.

Homepage.java

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        //String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    }

    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            // Set the Image in ImageView aimgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture loaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            nextPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Image_Recognition.class);
                    myintent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                    startActivity(myintent);
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
    }
```

Picture.java

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

The logcat is "JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"
It's very necessary for my app. But I can't find any solution of this.

Comment: It would be great if you add a full error log and the filesize of the image. I can only blind guess that it is too large for the binder. A similar error as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407821/how-to-solve-error-failed-binder-transaction-in-android-4-4

Comment: could be your array is too big, reduce the quality as `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);`

Comment: picture size is 592 kb.resolution 2048x1232

Comment: tried this. but nothing is changed

Comment: check the array size

Comment: how can i do this @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: `byteArray.length` and use log or toast to display it

Comment: it's 2361583 @Panveet_Singh

Comment: as i said it's 2.36MB which is quit high , so either compress image (Bitmap Options, google it) or send the path to next activity and recreate image there or some hack is use application class (google with hints)