# Failed Binder Transaction No Noticeable Problems

Tags: android, performance

If I'm getting a Failed Binder Transaction error but it's not noticeably affecting the functionality, does it still matter?

Is it making my app less efficient?

```
06-08 00:54:47.110: E/JavaBinder(10110): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

This error happens at the start of an activity where I load facebook photos into image views using Picasso. Based on some questions on stack overflow, I'm guessing it has to do with that:

```
String facebookProfilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+item.get(TAG_FACEBOOKID)+"/picture?width=80&height=80";

Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(facebookProfilePicUrl)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_person)
.into(holder.fbphoto);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Based on some questions on stack overflow, I'm guessing it has to do with that" -- probably not. Binder transactions are generated for Android's IPC mechanisms. You will get these for too-large extras, attempting to push too big of a `RemoteViews` to an app widget, etc.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have this same error and can't seem to fix it. Does this cause errors with the app? I am unable to load my friends list and I believe it is because of this failed binder transaction error.

Answer (score 2):

The Binder transaction likely failed because it was too large. Try scaling down the image beforehand, and refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528735/844882) for some more information.