# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION while passing Bitmap from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap, android-bundle

I want to pass a image as a bitmap from one activity to another. And i want to know whether it is possible to do like that.

**Sending Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BitmapActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("BITMAP", bitmap);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiving Activity**

```
Bundle bb = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    b = bb.getParcelable("BITMAP");
```

But i am getting **!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!** Error

Comment: is `bitmap`  a Bitmap Object?

Comment: yes it is. I am storing image in bitmap object.

Comment: you should not do that way. your are better off passing the path of the image to the next activity. Even if you compress as bytes and then pass it still takes more time.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a global class with a static bitmap object in it, something like this:

`public class Global {
  static Bitmap img;
}`

Before stating the activity by intent, assign your bitmap to this Global class attribute:

`Global.img = your_bitmap_img;`

After starting your activity, you can get back your bitmap by:

`bitmap_in_new_activity = Global.img;`

I know global variables are too dangerous for debugging but this technique helps us to transfer large data from one activity to another.The binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb  regardless of your device capabilities or your app.

Comment: this approach will surely help me, i was transferring many photos through the bundle and I could not go to the next activity. It took me a while to know there was a limit on how much a bundle can carry. Thanx Balaji Dubey

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] food = stream.toByteArray();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NoBoringActionBarActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.putExtra("picture", food);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Sending Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    byte[] food = extras.getByteArray("picture");
    Bitmap fo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(food, 0, food.length);
    mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
    //ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
    mHeaderLogo.setImageBitmap(fo);
```

Receiving Activity

Don't forget to place your image in drawable.