# Passing bitmap through intent (transaction error) vs. reloading it (OOM)

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform, bitmap, android-bitmap

This is more of a design question. I have a `MasterActivity` showing a not-so-little preview of an image, and a `DetailActivity` that should show the image in fullscreen.

Picture is retrieved from server using `parse.com` services and assigned to `ParseImageView`s, namely `view.setParseFile(file); view.loadInBackground()`. Average size is approx. `800x1000px`: thus picture is scaled down in master activity, bigger in detail. In both cases I refer to the same `800x1000px` file on the backend. Downloading takes some 2s. I do not want to store smaller sizes.

When the user taps a button, I need to pass this Bitmap (ParseFile, objectId, whatever) to `DetailActivity`, if it was loaded into the`MasterActivity`.

### Option1: Parcelable through Intent

**Issue: Binder Transaction Failed**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) picture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
i.putExtra("bitmap", b);
startActivity(i);
```

Doesn't work, getting `Binder Transaction Failed!`. It is well documented here on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285546/failed-binder-transaction-while-passing-bitmap-from-one-activity-to-another?rq=1)) that you can't pass objects larger than 1MB (more or less) like that.

### Option2: byte[] through Intent

**Issue: Binder Transaction Failed**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
i.putExtra("bitmap", bytes);
```

As suggested elsewhere I tried to compress the bitmap, but I'm getting the same size error. To avoid transaction limit here I should drop the quality down to 50 or so, and the result is not good to see.

### Option3: download the file again in DetailActivity.onCreate()

**Issue: OutOfMemoryError**

This was a promising option, but didn't work, throwing OOM. My debug opinion is that:

- I download the image in `MasterActivity`;
- I launch `DetailActivity`, while master is still in the backstack;
- I download a second instance of the picture, thus going OOM.

I'm stuck at this point. What can I do? If both activities could share the same Bitmap instance, I could avoid OOM.

Comment: Option #4: Don't use separate activities. Use one activity, with separate fragments. Option #5: *Very carefully* pass the image from activity to activity via a static data member, making sure to `null` out that static data member so you do not introduce a memory leak.

Comment: Save your file in assets directory and then access its.

Comment: @Commons I had read about #5 but was reluctant for obvious reasons. Is that what you would suggest? (given that #4 would require some hard work + implying design compromises)

Comment: @Vigen I believe writing+reading a File is like downloading it again - you have the master instance in memory, also, and doubling throws OOM.

Comment: Well, I would have gone with Option #4 from the outset (though note that it doesn't have to involve fragments, just so long as everything is in one activity). That being said, Option #5 should come "for free" from your image-loading library's memory cache. If you're not using an image-loading library or have not configured it's cache, I'd start there.

Comment: @Commons your configure-your-library clue made it. You can post an answer if you want.