# Taking photo from camera and setting that image in notification icon in android

Tags: android, notifications, icons

i want to set my camera picture as notification icon

this is my main activity

```
intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

........................

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
extras=data.getExtras();
bmp=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
}
```

from my broadcastreceiver i am trying to get the bitmap as

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
///////////////////////////................
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
 Notification notification2=new Notification.Builder(context).setTicker(from)
              .setContentTitle(from)
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
              .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
              .addAction(0,"remind",contentIntent).build();
```

but this is not working i'm getting force stop :(

Comment: i'm also tried 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
       Resources res = context.getResources();
       int height = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
       int width = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
       bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false); 
//////////////
//........
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
////..........
but still getting error

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you, if you could provide some output of the error message(s). Like the logcat Output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error

```
E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

it is due to the Bitmap being too big for the Android Binder (which I believe has a limit of 1 MB). You should look into compress the image before trying it to pass it in a Bundle. Take a look at this post: [Failed binder transaction when putting an bitmap dynamically in a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528735/failed-binder-transaction)