# Android : Update exicting Contact List

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am trying to edit my contact list through my App. I can able to update Contact name , Phone number and Email. But, when I try to change existing photo it is not updating.

When I try to add new contact with image it is successfully added

Problem occur when I try to edit existing Contact with Image

**Code that I using for Update Contact**

```
ContentResolver contentResolver  = getContentResolver();

            String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

            String[] emailParams = new String[]{idValue, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            String[] nameParams = new String[]{idValue, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            String[] numberParams = new String[]{idValue, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            int photoRow = -1;
            String wherePhoto = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + idValue + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " =='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, wherePhoto, null, null);
            int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
            }

            ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();


         ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,emailParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, edt_contactEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                    .build());



            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,nameParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, edt_contact_name.getText().toString().trim())
                    .build());


            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,numberParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, edt_contactNumber.getText().toString().trim())
                    .build());

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if(contact_bitmap!=null){    // If an image is selected successfully

                contact_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
                byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(photoRow)})
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, idValue)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA15, b)
                        .build());

                try {
                    stream.flush();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            try {
                contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                Toast.makeText(EditContacts.this,"Contact Successfully updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(EditContacts.this,MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);

            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Can any one please tell me how to edit existing contact with image.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this example for updating contact.
[ContactManager](https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/ContactManager)

Method to **update** Contact:

```
boolean updateContact(String contactID, String contactName, String contactNumber, String contactEmailAdd, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                        + "=?", new String[]{contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactName)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                        + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?"
                        , new String[]{contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                        , String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contactNumber)
                .build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                        + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?"
                        , new String[]{contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                        , String.valueOf(Email.TYPE_WORK)})
                .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, contactEmailAdd)
                .build());
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, image);

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{contactID, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                    .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray())
                    .build());

            /*Builder builder;
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                    new String[]{contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
            ops.add(builder.build());*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I try the method you given , but while executing am getting an error "JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"  @activesince93

Comment: Hope this helps: [Failed Binder transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18476263/3110234)

Comment: I just change bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, image);  now its workin. Thanks... @activesince93